# Reduce bandwith of XRDP

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop, xrdp

Due to the current pandemic, everyone in my corporation is in HomeOffice right now.
At work I have a Workstation running Linux, but for HomeOffice I got a laptop with Windows 10 on it. I just can't work with that ^^
So I set up a XRDP Server on my Workstation at work and connect with Windows' RDP Client to it.
So far so good (I'm doing that for almost a Year now).
But my problem is the bandwith that the RDP is using. Currently I can only use a resolution of 1366x768 (configured in the windows RDP Client). That works fine, but on my FHD Display I do work on a "tiny" Window. But my Workstation NetworkMonitor prompts, that it's sending approx. 90kb/s (which is fine). When I increase the configured Resolution, or even go to Fullscreen-Mode (1080p) the Workstation is senden ~2.5MB/s (which is a lot).
Due to our Network being shitty this makes working impossible.

So I'm looking for a way to reduce the network-load of my XRDP, so that I can work with a fullscreen resolution.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

*edit:

- I configured the colorsetting in the Windows' RDP-Client to the lowest possible already (HiColor 15Bit)
- I'm using `xrdp` and `xorgxrdp` from Ubuntus (18.04) repositories. So it's version 0.9.5
- I already tried to compile the latest version from source to enable rfx-codec, but I ran into the [blank screen issue](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1358)

Comment: Have you enabled caching and compression in [xrdp.ini](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-xrdp.ini/)?

Comment: yep, `bitmap_cache` `bitmap_compression` and `bulk_compression` is set true.